# Wordpress conditional statement for body to onload javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

Currently I am loading a google map api 3 java script this way in the header.php:

```
<body onload="initialize()" class="home page page-id-13 page-template page-template-page-FullWidth-php  u-design-responsive-on  u-design-menu-drop-shadows-on top-bg-color-dark ">
```

However, this loads initialize() on every page, which is bad. I would like it to only load on the home page, something like this (which isn't working):

```
<body <?php if(is_home()) { echo 'onload="initialize()"'}; body_class( array ($udesign_options['enable_cufon'], $udesign_responsive_body_class, $udesign_menu_auto_arrows, $udesign_menu_drop_shadows) )?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up using is this:

```
<body <?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { echo 'onload="initialize()"'; } ?> class="home page page-id-13 page-template page-template-page-FullWidth-php  u-design-responsive-on  u-design-menu-drop-shadows-on top-bg-color-dark ">
```

is_home apparently really means 'is_blog'

the is_home is actually unnecessary, unless it's a blog which in my case it is not, it's a static page.

Comment: Actually this is better since it doesn't echo a script tag which is not optimal:  <?php if(is_front_page()) { ?>
       <body <?php body_class(); ?> onload="initialize()"> 
<?php } else { ?>
       <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php } ?>

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the closing ">" after the "?>"

i.e.

You have: `<body <?php body_class($class); ?>`

But you should have: `<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>`

If that doesn't work, make sure you're not using query_posts before the call to is_home as this may be affecting the main loop, see here for more information: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts